# PostgreSQL - Before insert Trigger function is not working and giving syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger function in my PostgreSQL as follow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.buyer_participants_pid()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST null
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO buyer_participants VALUES (DEFAULT); 
    SET buyer_external_id = CONCAT('C', LPAD(CAST(CURRVAL('buyer_participants_id_seq') AS VARCHAR), 6, '0'));   
END; 
return buyer_external_id;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.ids_buyer_participants_creating_pid()
    OWNER TO postgres;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.ids_buyer_participants_creating_pid()
    IS 'null';
```

but i am getting following error instead.
[image]

I have check and tried to convert the syntax multiple time but this error is not fading away
this function with little syntax change work on mySQL but it is not working PostgreSQL

Comment: There is a `SET` command in PostgreSQL's SQL dialect, but it does *not* assign values to PL/pgSQL variables. Please review the basic syntax of PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Also from here [plgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): *A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.*.  This `return buyer_external_id;` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

In PL/pgSQL to assign a value into a variable you must have to declare it first. Also the `SET` command does not assign values to variables.

If I understood your function correctly, you simply need to return the identifier of the inserted record, and for that you do not need functions. You can use `RETURNING` instead, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO buyer_participants VALUES (DEFAULT)
RETURNING lpad(buyer_external_id::text, 6, '0');
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/AOnOUOPO)